Finding the sum of an alternating series which is like the harmonic series
Problem:
Find the sum of the following series:
$$ 1 - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{4} +  ... $$
Answer:
First observe that this is an alternating series and the magnitude of
each term is decreasing. Hence by the Leibniz's test we conclude the
series is convergent. In  attempt to find the sum, I am going to look
at some examples hoping to find a pattern.
\begin{align*}
S_2 &= \dfrac{1}{1} - \dfrac{1}{2} \\
S_2 &= \dfrac{1}{2} \\
S_3 &= \dfrac{1}{1} - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} \\
S_3 &=  S_2 + \dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3 }\\
S_3 &= \dfrac{5}{6} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
S_4 &= \dfrac{1}{1} - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{4} \\
S_4 &= S_3 - \dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{5}{6}  - \dfrac{1}{4} \\
S_4 &= \dfrac{ 5(4) - 6 }{24 } \\
S_4 &= \dfrac{ 7 }{ 12 } \\
S_5 &= \dfrac{1}{1} - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{5} \\
S_5 &= S_4 + \dfrac{1}{5} \\
S_5 &=  \dfrac{ 7 }{ 12 } + \dfrac{1}{5} = \dfrac{ 7(5)+ 12 }  { 12(5) } \\
S_5 &= \dfrac{47 }{ 60 }
\end{align*}
I will try again.
\begin{align*}
S &=
 \left(  \dfrac{1}{1} - \dfrac{1}{2}  \right)
 + \left(  \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{4} \right) 
 + \left(  \dfrac{1}{5} - \dfrac{1}{6}  \right)  + ... \\
S &= \dfrac{ 2 - 1 } { 1(2)} + \dfrac{ 4 - 3 } { 3(4)} + \dfrac{ 6 - 5 } { 5(6)} + ... \\
S &= \dfrac{ 1 } { 1(2)} + \dfrac{ 1 } { 3(4)} + \dfrac{1 } { 5(6)} + ... \\
S &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{ 1 } { (2i-1)(2i) }
\end{align*}
Again, I feel stuck.
What is the right way to solve this problem?

The Taylor series of Ln(x) should assist you well

MacLaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$

There isn't necessarily a single "right" way to solve it, but the comments have given a pretty good hint. Assuming you don't know about Taylor series but do have a bit of basic calculus, we can do the following:
Consider the function defined by the series $f(x) = x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3} x^3 - \frac{1}{4} x^4 + \ldots = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{n + 1}$, so we are ultimately looking to find the value $f(1)$. Note that the series is absolutely convergent for $|x| < 1$ (which you can prove by comparison to the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$), and conditionally convergent for $x = 1$.
We can differentiate $f$ term-by-term, giving $f'(x) = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \ldots$, which we recognise as a geometric series with initial term $1$ and ratio $-x$, so at least in the interval $x \in (-1, 1)$ we can resolve this to $f'(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x}$.
We can then try to find $f(x)$ by integrating, i.e. $f(x) = \int \frac{dx}{1 + x}$, noting that:

This is only valid on the interval $|x| < 1$ thanks to the dominated convergence theorem; and

The integral will only get us to $f$ up to a constant, so we need to find some kind of initial value to work from - and thankfully, we can see that $f(0) = 0$.


This should get you just about all the way to the answer, using a continuity argument to get to the boundary of the convergence interval.
